# How to declare a hasEq constraint?

Tags: fstar

I'm just starting out with F*, by which I mean I've written a few lines along with the tutorial. So far it's really interesting and I'd like to keep learning.

The first thing I tried to do on my own was to write a type that represents a non-empty list. This was my attempt:

```
type nonEmptyList 'a = l : (list 'a) { l <> [] }
```

But I get the error

> Failed to verify implicit argument: Subtyping check failed; expected
>   type (a#6468:Type{(hasEq a@0)}); got type Type

I know I'm on the right track though because, if I constrain my list type to containing strings, this *does* work:

```
type nonEmptyList = l : (list string) { l <> [] }
```

I'm assuming this means that `l <> []` in the original example isn't valid because I haven't specified that `'a` should support equality. The problem is that I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do that. I guess is has something to do with a higher kind called `hasEq`, but trying things such as:

```
type nonEmptyList 'a = l : (list 'a) { hasEq 'a /\ l <> [] }
```

hasn't gotten me anywhere. The tutorial doesn't cover `hasEq` and I can't find anything helpful in the examples in the GitHub repo so now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You correctly identified the problem here. The type `'a` that you used in the definition of `nonEmptyList` is left unspecified and therefore could not support equality. Your intuition is correct, you need to tell F* that `'a` is a type that has equality, by adding a refinement on it:

To do that, you can write the following:

```
type nonEmptyList (a:Type{hasEq a}) = l : (list a) { l <> [] }
```

Note that the binder I used for the type is `a` and not `'a`. It would cause a syntax error, it makes more sense because it isn't "any" type anymore.
Also, note that you can be even more precise and specify the universe of the type `a` as `Type0` if needbe.

Comment: Thank you for this! It works, although specifying that `a` supports equality feels like a hack to get what I want. Do you know how I can accomplish this without it? It seems that I can `match` a list value against `[]` without equality, but I can't use the `<>` operator...

Answer (score 3):

Your analysis is indeed correct, and the accepted answer gives the right solution in general.

For your concrete example, though, you don't need decidable equality on list elements: you can just use `(list 'a){ ~ (List.isEmpty l) }`.

For reference, here's the definition of `isEmpty`:

```
(** [isEmpty l] returns [true] if and only if [l] is empty  *)
val isEmpty: list 'a -> Tot bool
let isEmpty l = match l with
  | [] -> true
  | _ -> false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Clément. This brings up an interesting question about type systems in general: surely all empty lists are the same? I should be able to compare *any* list to [], even if the contained type of the list does not support equality.

Comment: Right – and that's essentially what isEmpty is doing.